# Subset data frame for rows equal to one value but the other

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1001:1004), each = 3), value = c(1,1,4,1,2,3,2,2,5,1,5,6))

df
     id value
1  1001     1
2  1001     1
3  1001     4
4  1002     1
5  1002     2
6  1002     3
7  1003     2
8  1003     2
9  1003     5
10 1004     1
11 1004     5
12 1004     6
```

What is a good way to return me the IDs that have value equals to `1` but `3`, i.e., any ID that has its corresponding value equals to `3` will be excluded but must have at least one value equals to `1`? In this case, `ID 1002` has `1` but also has `3` and shall be excluded. `ID 1003` doesn't have any value equals to `1` and shall be excluded too. So `ID 1001 and 1004` will be returned. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the ID's that contain 1 with `df$id[df$value == 1]`, and likewise for 3 `df$id[df$value == 3]`. To exclude one set from the other, you can use `setdiff`.

In one command: `with(df,setdiff(id[value == 1],id[value == 3]))`

Answer (score 0):

This is another alternative.

```
unique(df$id[df$value==1][! df$id[df$value==1] %in% df$id[df$value==3]])
[1] 1001 1004
```